# Приостановить заргузку с пропеллером на несколько секунд

Tags: xcode, ios

Доброго времени суток. В общем, суть такая: нужно приостановить заргузку с пропеллером, т.е. при нажатии на кнопку выскакивает вьюшка с пропеллером типа подождите, только потом происходит переход на другой контроллер. Так вот, подскажите, пожалуйста, как на пару секунд остановить это окно, типа сис-ма подбирает что-то для вас... Заранее извиняюсь за свой ломаный язык

код выглядит так

```
- (IBAction)bottomSecondSearchAction:(id)sender
{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // time-consuming task
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        });
    });

}
```

!Пробую вставлять [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 2], но он сначала засыпает, а потом на секунду выскакивает окошко  и переход соответственно...

Comment: @byldog05, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @alvoro, Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Нужно скрывать индикатор (пропеллер, ромашку, крутилку) в таком блоке (вместо вложенного dispatch_async):

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(<some_seconds> * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                             [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                         });
```